# Knex's whereIn behaved as whereNotIn when passing an array of objects, is this intended behaviour?

Tags: knex.js

```
validos = [{equipamento: 'OM908002'}];

knex.showtecsystem('contratos_veiculos')
.select(['equipamento', 'uso_tornozeleira'])
.whereIn('equipamento', validos)
```

In this query, the whereIn actually returns what was expected to get from an whereNotIn. As a result of passing an array of objects intead of an array of strings.

Is this really intended behaviour?  It actually led to an incorrect update where a modified all but the rows I didn't intend to (could have been a huge hassle), and I don't see it disclosed in the API's documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `[{equipamento: 'OM908002'}]` to `.whereIn('equipamento', validos)` when you should have passed `['OM908002']`.